# Programmatically checked checkboxes in DGV do not show as checked

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm using a datagridview for some parts of my user rights management.
For each right, there's at least one column of checkboxes in the DGV.
These checkboxes are created by using [DataGridViewCheckBoxColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.8)

These can be checked and unchecked either normally or with a context menu for mass (un)-checking (check all, uncheck all, reverse all).
Naturally, the mass (un)-checking is then done programmatically. Example code fragment "reverse all":

```cs
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgv.Rows)
{
    dr.Cells[gridcol.Index].Value = !Convert.ToBoolean(dr.Cells[gridcol.Index].Value);
}
```

Under very specific conditions, the status of a checkbox doesn't refresh properly:

- Left-click a cell with a checkbox in the DGV (not necessarily (un)checking the checkbox in the process)
- Click a context menu button that would change the clicked cell's content

The checking status appears to stay unchanged. However, if you click somewhere else to select a different row, apparently the checking status refreshes.

I've tried programmatically clearing the selection and selecting different rows, but that doesn't appear to fix the problem - it seems that you actually need to click a different row to solve said issue.

```cs
dgv.ClearSelection();
dgv.Rows[2].Selected = true; //Row 2 is just a random one for the sake of testing it
tbCtrlRights_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
```

Comment: [DataGridView.EndEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.endedit?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Oh, so simple! I think I stumbled accross EndEdit a while ago, but I wouldn't have thought that it applies to this specific case as well - it figured it was for changing the schema/structure of the dgv. Thanks!